# Run html+css+js application as a Mac OS X app

Tags: macos, applications, desktop, web-app

I'm completely new to development for Mac OS X but I want to have a Mac desktop app for my  own small project. What I have in my mind is to have web application (will use the same app running on the web) running in some kind of wrapper window and pack everything in .app file so it could be run just by clicking icon and will not run in a browser.

So in short - I have web application written in html+css+js and want to run in some kind of wrapper and make it look and act like desktop app. The best way to do that?

Do I need to write some kind of wrapper app in Objective-C which basically will have window and will use WebKit to load my files? Or maybe there is already a solution for it which could be used?

The best example I can find quickly of this is http://brackets.io/ where a web app is packaged to look like a compiled app and runs on my Mac.

Comment: What's wrong with opening it in a browser? By definition, it will not look and act like a desktop app if you are not using the standard controls the OS provides.

Comment: I want to distribute it easier. And yes, I know that it will not act like native desktop app... I also found something like https://github.com/maccman/macgap/blob/master/README.md maybe it will be what I need...

Comment: An .app is more difficult to distribute than a hyperlink.

Comment: Gerry, hyperlink is useful only if you have internet connection. .app will be useful anytime.

Comment: Sounds like something that could be a Dashboard Widget. Apple has a Dashcode development environment for creating packaged webpages with html+css+js. Not really an answer, as you are looking for an .app.

Comment: Dashboard widget is not the things I look for, but thanks David ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) to create a site-specific browser. SSBs often feel more like restricted versions of browsers than standalone applications though.

One example of a Fluid application is https://github.com/drdrang/drtwoot.

Comment: Tried Fluid, but if I'm right then another person will need to install Fluid to be able to run my .app? Right?

Comment: @IgnasB. No, they can be run even if Fluid wasn't installed.

Comment: Then maybe it's the easiest way to go... :) Will check. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found MacGap2, but it's still in development.
https://github.com/MacGapProject/MacGap2

It is a Xcode project and just compiles to an app with a WebView. You just put your html/css/js app in the public folder and hit the build button.

It does almost the same as Fluid, only it hasn't got a javascript api (yet).

**EDIT:** I found a second **better solution** based on nodejs, [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) (node-webkit framework). It's in development, but cross platform for MacOS, Linux and Windows.
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js

I found several apps that use nwjs. One is http://koala-app.com

**EDIT 2:** I now use http://electron.io

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [PHP Nighttrain](https://www.naetech.com/php-nightrain)? True, it utilizes PHP, but HTML to PHP isn't too hard to do. Nighttrain is in active development & is open source.

Answer (score 0):

try [nw.js](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) (formerly node-webkit). originally developed at intel, it’s very fast, super-easy to use and "compiles" for OS X, Windows and Linux Graphic Shells. Also, there’s a lively community, which is always a good thing.